# Why created method is not working in vue-resources?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I'm a beginner with Vue.js, i installed vue resources with the below steps:

- `npm install vue-resources --save`
- in main.js: `import VueResource from 'vue-resource'`
- in main.js: `Vue.use(VueResource);`

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Users/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Users from './components/Users'
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            Users
        }
    }
</script>
```

Users.vue:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Users',
        methods: {
            created: function(){
                console.log('Test Message');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Nothing happened in the console.

Created function is not working, anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to vue-resources and cannot be affected by it, unless it caused an error on initialization.

`created` is lifecycle hook and not user-defined method, therefore it shouldn't be specified in `methods`.

It should be:

```
export default {
    name: 'Users',
    created: function(){
        console.log('Test Message');
    }
}
```